# How to read and display the contents of a text file chosen from a file chooser in android app?

Tags: java

I'm a newbie to android app development. I'm trying to read and display a text file chosen from a file chooser in a textview in my app. But with the following code my app keeps crashing. Initially when I put a toast after filePath = data.getData(); It was working and when I converted filePath (which has data type of Uri) to String and then put a toast just to make sure if Uri is being converted to String, it worked, I got the path of file in the toast but when I implemented the read_file() function my app crashed. I'm a newbie any help would be appreciated.

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        if (requestCode == FILE_SELECT_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {


            filePath = data.getData();

            read_file(this,filePath);

        }
        }


    public String read_file(Context context, Uri filePath) {
        try {


            String uriToString;
            uriToString= filePath.toString();
            Toast.makeText(this, uriToString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(uriToString);
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            return sb.toString();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            return "";
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return "";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you want to print the file contents?

Comment: ...in a textview